# TestCafe - Shared singleton between testcafe and application

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have an application running with `Vue`, and I am using `testcafe` to do end-to-end testing.

### MyModule.ts

```
class MyModule {
    public value: string;

    constructor() {}
}

export default new MyModule();
```

### Test cafe file

```
import MyModule from '../models/utils/MyModule';

fixture('Getting Started')
  .page('http://localhost:8080/en/home/')
  .before(async (ctx) => {
    MyModule.value = 'Set by Test Cafe';
  });

test('Get to the home page', async (t) => {
  ....
});
```

### App.vue

```
<template>.....</template>
<script>
    import TeMyModulestModule from '@/test/e2e/models/utils/MyModule';
    export default {
    
        created() {
          console.log('MyModule.value', MyModule.value);
        }
    }
</script>
```

### Actual result

> MyModule.value undefined

### Expected result

> MyModule.value 'Set by Test Cafe'

### Question

Is it possible to achieve this with testCafe? If so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TestCafe test fixture is a regular node.js script, and it is executed on the server side. You are trying to share your module between different contexts (node.js server-side and browser client-side).

You can put the specified value into the global `window` object using the [ClientFunction](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402832/guides/basic-guides/obtain-client-side-info) or [Inject Client Scripts](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402843/guides/advanced-guides/inject-client-scripts) approach and obtain it from the Vue script.